# I need to send a file via curl using powershell , is this possible?

Tags: powershell, curl, command, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a powershell script to upload a file to this site. They orginally suggested using command prompt and the command they provided does run but i have to manually go in and change the directory before and I dont know how to do it in a script with command prompt. I tried doing it in Powershell so I can set the directory at the beginning and automate , pls review.

command prompt script (runs):

```
-curl ‐i ‐F filedata=@"C:\PBIS\PBISstudent.csv" -u"DoughertyCountyDL":"20PBi$"
```

(this runs but I need have to go in manually and change the directory then send it)

powershell script (doesnt run):

```
Set-Location -Path "E:\bin"
-curl ‐i ‐F filedata=@"C:\PBIS\PBISstudent.csv" -u"DoughertyCountyDL":"20PBi$" 
"https://datalink.pbisapps.org/api/2/Students/File"
```

(The error i get is that it doesnt recognize curl as a cmdlet but i have the path specified to where the curl.exe is located so I dont understand.. )

Comment: call `.\curl.exe` (with the extension) instead of `curl`

Comment: When I use that it ran but gave me an error saying credentials were wrong but they are actually correct and run in the command prompt..

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>

Comment: Please add your error message to your question body to be more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell's native cmdlet is `Invoke-WebRequest`.
Here is the link to the documentation to submit a file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--submit-a-multipart-form-data-file

This cmdlet also has a credential parameter which should also resolve your 'Unauthorized' error.

Comment: Ok so can you help me convert the provided code I attempted, using invoke-webrequest? Its not making sense to me im a complete novice to powershell. Im trying to see if I can do a change directory in a command prompt batch now